# facebook native android app does not accept my key hash

Tags: android, hash, key, native

i am using windows 7. trying to create new native android app.
to generate the key hash i wrote the following line in the cmd
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_25\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey
 -keystore C:\Users\Youske.android\debug.keystore | C:\openssl\bin\openssl sha1
 -binary | C:\openssl\bin\openssl base64

i enter the password : android 
and i got my key hash : 0UzmruCvZLUgljxZvly3B34D7zA=
then i enable Configured for Android SSO: , then i copy this key to the "android key hash" texterea , click on save changes , and facebook generate to me the next error :

Error
You have enabled a Native Android App integration for your app, but have not specified the Android Key Hash. For security reasons, the Facebook application will not interact with any native application that does not have a signature that matches a corresponding key hash.

so if any one face this problem please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact problem, and fixed it by simply using Firefox instead of Google Chrome. Hope this helps!

Comment: have the same, but in my case works in chrome, but not in firefox.